# No error but load infile in .sql file not working in python script

Tags: python, mysql

I have .sql file which has multiple load commands as follows,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'csvname.csv' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES(....);
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'csvname.csv' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES(....);
```

Which runs perfectly in SQL terminal but in the script I don't get any error still not loading

My code:

```
#db = pymysql.connect(**db_opts)
conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5,local_infile=True)
cur = conn.cursor()
print ("Connected!\n")
for line in open('load.sql','r'):
    print(line)
    cur.execute(line)
conn.close()
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pymysql doesnot support load command.